# Не реагирует sqlite3 при работе с телеграм-ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlite3

**КОД:**

```
def *add_night_cleaner*(user_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('nc.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO night VALUES(?, ?);', ((1, user_id), ))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


@dp.message_handler(commands=cmd, state='*')
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    go = int(datetime.datetime.now().time().hour)
    if go >= 6:
        print('go')
        user_id = message.chat.id
        night_cleaner.add_night_cleaner(user_id=user_id)
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text='XXX')
```

Функция `add_night_cleaner` отлично работает вне бота, а в телеграм-боте не вызывается и не выводится ошибка. Сколько использую ее никогда ошибок не выводилось. Про то что функция не асинхронная знаю, но она будет вызываться раз в день и это не критичный момент

Comment: Начать стоит с логичного вопроса — а функция send_welcome вызывается-то?

Comment: да, и работает, там еще другое продолжение есть и оно работает "go" пишется

Comment: Тогда как вы определяете, что add_night_cleaner "не реагирует"?

Comment: во время работы функции go в строке пишется и остальные функции в этой функции работают (скинул фрагмент) а именно эта нет. Ошибка не выводится просто не реагирует никак. Не добавляет юзера в БД